# Reference specific github repo version in Cordova's config.xml

Tags: cordova, github, version

I specify all of the plugins for my Cordova project in `config.xml` in order to automate my build process. In order to avoid breaking my build process when authors update their plugins, I need to lock every plugin at a certain version, just like in a `package.json` or gem file. This is easy enough for official plugins:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />                                                                                                                                    
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="^1.0.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="^1.0.0" />
```

I don't know why there are two different syntaxes, but this seems to be working and is what is generated by the cordova CLI tool itself.

Amazingly, I can't find any documentation whatsoever for how to lock versions for Github repositories.

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-google-analytics"
  spec="https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin.git" />
```

This feels so... naked. Is there some extra syntax I can use in `spec`, like this?

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-google-analytics"
  spec="https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin.git@1.2.3" />
```

Or should I use `version`, perhaps?

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-google-analytics"
  spec="https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin.git" version="1.2.3" />
```

Note that I regularly regenerate the project from scratch in my build environment and that the solution needs to be automated.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with the `cordova plugin add --save` command and looking at the output, I figured out that you can replace the git URL in `spec` with a version string.

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-google-analytics" spec="1.2.3" />
```

This solved my problem with the breaking changes in the library.